# Can't read key from memcached using dalli

Tags: ruby, memcached, telnet, dalli

[`dalli`](https://github.com/mperham/dalli) refuses to connect and read from a remote `memcached` server, but `telnet` works just fine.

I have connected to a remote server via SSH, and forwarded a memcached port over to my machine like this:

```
Host access.production
  HostName 1.2.3.4
  LocalForward 10001 9.8.7.6:11211
```

Now that I try to read keys from `memcached` using `telnet`, it works just fine:

```
$ telnet localhost 10001
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

However, the following Ruby script using dalli will fail:

```
require 'dalli'

client = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:10001')
client.get('my_key')
```

**Why `dalli` wouldn't connect to memcached, while `telnet` – will?**

**Updated**. `dalli` returns this error:

```
I, [2015-07-17T11:22:36.839807 #4286]  INFO -- : localhost:10001 failed (count: 0) Timeout::Error: IO timeout: {:host=>"localhost", :port=>10001, :down_retry_delay=>1, :socket_timeout=>0.5, :socket_max_failures=>2, :socket_failure_delay=>0.01, :value_max_bytes=>1048576, :compressor=>Dalli::Compressor, :compression_min_size=>1024, :compression_max_size=>false, :serializer=>Marshal, :username=>nil, :password=>nil, :keepalive=>true}
/Users/gmile/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@portal/gems/dalli-2.7.2/lib/dalli/ring.rb:45:in `server_for_key': No server available (Dalli::RingError)
    from /Users/gmile/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@portal/gems/dalli-2.7.2/lib/dalli/client.rb:328:in `perform'
    from /Users/gmile/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4@portal/gems/dalli-2.7.2/lib/dalli/client.rb:53:in `get'
    from dali_all_keys.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: In what way does it fail?

Comment: @FrederickCheung my apologies, I have just updated the question with the error message.

Comment: What's the latency like? Dalli's default timeout is 0.5s

Comment: @FrederickCheung you're right! Increasing the timeout helped, thanks! If only you could post this as an answer to question, I would gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Dalli timeout is 500ms. Given that memcache response times are typically single digit milliseconds, and that you put your memcache instances close to your servers this is usually ample.

On the other hand given that you are connecting via an ssh tunnel you might see much greater latencies you might want to increase the timeout:

```
 Dalli::Client.new("127.0.0.1:10001", socket_timeout: 2.0)
```